# DNA replication in $ E.coli $

Tags: microbiology, dna-replication, experiment

$ E.coli $ has circular DNA which I guess implies one strand forms the outer circle and the other the inner one. So, is there a way to know if the replicated DNA forms the outer or inner circle?
In the image attached it is seen that the replicated DNA forms the inner circle. Also mentioned is the fact that it is not possible to make out individual strands by TEM.[image][image]

Comment: The picture on the bottom is a simplified cartoon. The two strands make a double helix so they both alternate between top strand and bottom strand. Also plasmids aren't 2D circles in the cell; they twist and turn and rotate.